# Is it possible to use nvidia Nsight to debug cppwinrt directx12 applications?

Tags: windows-10-universal, nsight, directx-12, c++-winrt

I have a UWP cppwinrt app that is using directx12 to render a cube with a basic shader. I would like to use a graphics debugger to inspect the data being sent to this shader.

First I am trying to use the Nvidia Nsight debugger for visual studio 2017. The problem is that when I go to "Start Graphics Debugging" from the Nsight menu, the app immediately stop with an error saying: "Failed to launch UWP app (Could not terminate existing process)".

I am able to launch the Nsight debugger on a DirectX12 UWP app (C++/CX) created from the visual studio template though which is encouraging.

My cppWinRT app is rendering to a swapchain created using `IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForComposition` like so:

```
    check_hresult(
        m_factory->CreateSwapChainForComposition(
            m_commandQueue.get(),
            &swapChainDesc,
            nullptr,
            m_swapChain.put()
    ));

    // associate DXGI swap chain with the XAML SwapChainPanel
    check_hresult(
        swapChainPanel().as<ISwapChainPanelNative>()->SetSwapChain(m_swapChain.get())
    );
```

The `swapChainPanel()` is a `winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::SwapChainPanel` xaml control.

Does anyone have an idea how this could be done?

UPDATE 8/13/2018:

I tried using Nsight with a different project from Microsoft that is very similar to mine, which you can find here: https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/feature_xaml_template/Templates/DirectX12XamlApp

It has the exact same problem as my project so it seems like the `swapChainPanel` XAML control is the problem.

I suspect that a possible workaround would be to present using a different swapchain when debugging, such as one created with `IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow` instead.

Comment: C++/WinRT is in no way special. It accesses the same Windows Runtime API surface as your DirectX 12 UWP app, regardless of the language projection used by that template (C#, C++/CX, any other). It appears that you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @IInspectable Ok it’s good to know that I can trust that cppWinRT is not the problem. There’s definitely some differences between the two apps. I will update the question with more details.

Comment: Does your app work in normal Visual Studio debugger model?

Comment: Yes I've been using the visual studio debugger a lot to create the app.

Comment: Could you share a sample that could reproduce this issue?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Yep I just updated the question with a link to a microsoft sample that has the same issue.

Comment: Ok, I will check.

Comment: I could reproduce your issue, but there is no NV driver in my side, so I can not rule out NV driver issue, and have you tested in NV driver environment?

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. I’m not sure if I understood you correctly though. Are you saying that you have reproduced the issue in an environment with no nvidia drivers so you think its possible it might be caused by the nvidia drivers? I have tested with the latest nvidia drivers.

Comment: If it also does not work in NV driver environment,  you could report this to [nsight community](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/).