# Can't activate CoreWindow in cppWinRT UWP app

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

I have a simple cppWinRT app created from the "Blank App" visual studio template. I add 2 buttons with the following handlers:

```cpp
Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction MainPage::ClickHandler(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
    OutputDebugStringW((L"\n Entered the function : " + std::to_wstring(GetCurrentThreadId()) + L"\n").c_str());

    coreView = winrt::Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplication::CreateNewView();

    OutputDebugStringW((L"\n Created the view : " + std::to_wstring(GetCurrentThreadId()) + L"\n").c_str());

    co_await resume_foreground(coreView.Dispatcher());
    auto appView = winrt::Windows::UI::ViewManagement::ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView();
    m_window_debug = Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread();
    OutputDebugStringW((L"\n Switched thread : " + std::to_wstring(GetCurrentThreadId()) + L"\n").c_str());

    hstring newTitle = L"my new window";
    appView.Title(newTitle);
    OutputDebugStringW((L"\n Set new title : " + std::to_wstring(GetCurrentThreadId()) + L"\n").c_str());

    m_window_debug.Activated([&, this](auto&& sender, auto&& e) {
        OutputDebugStringW((L"\n sender ActivationMode : " + std::to_wstring(static_cast<int>(sender.ActivationMode())) + L"\n").c_str());
        OutputDebugStringW((L"\n sender ActivationState : " + std::to_wstring(static_cast<int>(e.WindowActivationState())) + L"\n").c_str());
    });

    OutputDebugStringW((L"\n Registered the callback : " + std::to_wstring(GetCurrentThreadId()) + L"\n").c_str());
}

Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction MainPage::ClickHandler2(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
{
    co_await resume_foreground(coreView.Dispatcher());
    Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread().Activate();
    OutputDebugStringW((L"\n After activation : " + std::to_wstring(static_cast<int>(m_window_debug.ActivationMode())) + L"\n").c_str());

}
```

I expect that when I click the button1 and enter `ClickHandler` that a new view is created and ready to be activated so that when I click on button2 and enter `ClickHandler2` that my newly created view gets activated and thus become visible.

Instead what happens is that the view doesnt change and I get the following output in the console:

I click Button1

```
Entered the function : 33084

Created the view : 33084

Switched thread : 8928

Set new title : 8928

Registered the callback : 8928
```

I click Button2

```
After activation : 0
```

Now the strange thing is that if I put a breakpoint anywhere in either `ClickHandler` or `ClickHandler2`, and then press F10 to step over, and then F5 to continue, it does work and the new view becomes visible with the new title. The output looks like this:

I click Button1

```
 Entered the function : 32432

 Window created : 5268

 Created the view : 32432

 Switched thread : 5268

 Set new title : 5268

 Registered the callback : 5268
```

I click Button2, break on a line in `ClickHandler2`, Step Over and Continue.

```
 After activation : 0

 sender ActivationMode : 3

 sender ActivationState : 0

 sender ActivationMode : 1

 sender ActivationState : 1
```

At this point new view is visible and it works.

How come I have to break into the code in order for my new view to become visible?

Comment: What is your app target version? Could you provide a simple sample project to help me see this issue?

Comment: Here's a sample that shows the same problem: https://github.com/maximebl/so_repro

Answer (score 1):

As the document of [winrt::resume_foreground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/resume-foreground), this API's Minimum supported SDK: Windows SDK Insider Preview version 10.0.17661.0 (Windows 10, version 1803). If you test it using the SDK Version 17134 on the device version 17134, it is not the matching environment.

You can test your project on the device with OS insider preview Version equal or higher than 17661 and change your app target version to the corresponding insider preview SDK version. See [Windows Insider Preview Downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewSDK). I tried to test your sample with UWP app target version 17744, min version 17134 on the device with OS version 17746, it works well.

Comment: Thank you for that information. I did get that preview build and managed to get the app to compile and run (I'm talking about the app called so_repro that I linked in my last comment). It's true that it does show a window when you click on the button, however notice that the window is not activated (hence the title of this question). I tried manually activating it with Window::Current().CoreWindow().Activate() but it still doesnt activate it. Since then I have figured out that I need to add a Xaml Frame element to the window in order for it to activate because this is a xaml app.

Comment: Adding a Xaml Frame to the view actually causes a very specific problem for my use case, because I want to use the CoreWindow to create a DirectX swapchain. And it turns out that if I I add a Xaml Frame to it, the call to IDXGIFactory2::CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow fails with an "access denied" error. So now the question is, how can I activate a new view WITHOUT adding a xaml frame to it.

Comment: You can try to add a Frame, then put a [SwapChainPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.swapchainpanel) into the Frame. The [SwapChainPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.swapchainpanel) provides a hosting surface, where Microsoft DirectX swap chains provide content that can be rendered into a XAML UI. Also see the code from [XAML SwapChainPanel DirectX interop sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-SwapChainPanel-00cb688b).

Comment: Yea thats actually what in already doing :) The catch is that I absolutely need a second viewport that uses CreateSwapchainForComposition with a CoreWindow because the nvidia nsight debugger for visual studio only works with that.

Comment: I have a seperate question that explains what I just said in my comment in more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51807703/is-it-possible-to-use-nvidia-nsight-to-debug-cppwinrt-directx12-applications?noredirect=1#comment90619747_51807703